# Why code behave different in c# Interactive (Roslyn) and in debug\release mode?

Tags: c#, https, webclient, tls1.2

**Update**
Actually after digging around net monitoring I found difference in way request is made by code executed Roslyn and normal debug\release mode.
Under debug\release mode Fiddler trace error:

```
[Fiddler] The connection to 'host.com' failed.  <br/>System.Security.SecurityException Failed to negotiate HTTPS connection with server.fiddler.network.https&gt; HTTPS handshake to host.com (for #76) failed. System.IO.IOException Unable to read data from the transport connection: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host. &lt; An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host
```

**Original question**:
I got a piece of code:

```
HttpTransportOverWebClient c = new HttpTransportOverWebClient();
c.GetURL("https://web.page/query")
```

Where GetUrl is some wrapper:

```
public bool GetURL(string URL)
        {
            try
            {
                web.Headers.Add("User-Agent", browserAgent);
                byte[] data = web.DownloadData(URL);
                string characterSet = web.Response.CharacterSet;
                string encoding = (characterSet == null || characterSet == "" || characterSet.ToUpper() == "NONE") ? "UTF-8" : web.Response.CharacterSet.ToUpper();
                html = Encoding.GetEncoding(encoding).GetString(data);
                return true;
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                lastException = web.LastException == null ? new WebException(ex.Message) : web.LastException;
            }
            return false;
        }
```

Behavior in c#Interactive mode:

> GetURL return true and html contains data

Behavior in debug\release mode:

> GetURL return false and ex contains error below:

```
An exception occurred during a WebClient request.
   at System.Net.WebClient.DownloadDataInternal(Uri address, WebRequest& request)
   at System.Net.WebClient.DownloadData(Uri address)
   at HttpCrawler.HttpTransportOverWebClient.GetURL(String URL) in ..HttpTransportOverWebClient.cs:line xx
```

Inner exception:

```
 at System.Net.WebClient.DownloadBitsState.SetResponse(WebResponse response)
   at System.Net.WebClient.DownloadBits(WebRequest request, Stream writeStream, CompletionDelegate completionDelegate, AsyncOperation asyncOp)
   at System.Net.WebClient.DownloadDataInternal(Uri address, WebRequest& request)
```

Pleas advice

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Solution**

I suppose  C#interactive pre-configured in some way that it capable to default ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol to a older version. As a resolution I add to a code:

```
using System.Net;
....
ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = 
       SecurityProtocolType.Tls11 | SecurityProtocolType.Tls12;
```